# Why won't trump animate during his jump?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to make trump enter his jump animation when he jumps. How do I make this work? I keep getting errors.

```
var jump = false;
var speed = 3.0;
var object;
var trump;
var jumpAnim : AnimationClip;
function Start()
{
trump = GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);
GetComponent.<Animation>().AddClip(jumpAnim, "jumpAnim");
var object = GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);
}

function OnCollisionEnter2D(collision: Collision2D) {
    jump = false;
    trump.velocity.y = 0;
}


function FixedUpdate() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        trump.AddForce(Vector2(-4,0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        trump.AddForce(Vector2(1,0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        if (jump == false) {
            Animation.Play("jumpAnim");
            trump.AddForce(Vector2(0, 10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            jump = true;
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
        trump.AddForce(Vector2(0, -0.5), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
    if (trump.position.y <= -5)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(0);
    }
```

It just won't make him animate. And I have no clue how to revert to the old animation either. The game keeps telling me he doesn't have an animation, but they are all there, so what is happening? How do I fix it?

[image]
[image]